# Render SVG Symbol Sprite with linearGradient

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, sprite

I have this svg file

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
     focusable="false"
     width="0"
     height="0"
     visibility="hidden"
     style="
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
    "
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
   
    <symbol id='instagram' viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none">
        <path d="M13.6 5.60001C9.18238 5.60001 5.59998 9.18241 5.59998 13.6V26.4C5.59998 30.8176 9.18238 34.4 13.6 34.4H26.4C30.8176 34.4 34.4 30.8176 34.4 26.4V13.6C34.4 9.18241 30.8176 5.60001 26.4 5.60001H13.6ZM29.6 8.80001C30.4832 8.80001 31.2 9.51681 31.2 10.4C31.2 11.2832 30.4832 12 29.6 12C28.7168 12 28 11.2832 28 10.4C28 9.51681 28.7168 8.80001 29.6 8.80001ZM20 12C24.4176 12 28 15.5824 28 20C28 24.4176 24.4176 28 20 28C15.5824 28 12 24.4176 12 20C12 15.5824 15.5824 12 20 12ZM20 15.2C18.7269 15.2 17.506 15.7057 16.6059 16.6059C15.7057 17.5061 15.2 18.727 15.2 20C15.2 21.273 15.7057 22.4939 16.6059 23.3941C17.506 24.2943 18.7269 24.8 20 24.8C21.273 24.8 22.4939 24.2943 23.3941 23.3941C24.2943 22.4939 24.8 21.273 24.8 20C24.8 18.727 24.2943 17.5061 23.3941 16.6059C22.4939 15.7057 21.273 15.2 20 15.2Z" fill="currentColor"/> 
    </symbol>

    <symbol id='instagram-gradient' viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none">
        <path d="M13.6 5.60001C9.18238 5.60001 5.59998 9.18241 5.59998 13.6V26.4C5.59998 30.8176 9.18238 34.4 13.6 34.4H26.4C30.8176 34.4 34.4 30.8176 34.4 26.4V13.6C34.4 9.18241 30.8176 5.60001 26.4 5.60001H13.6ZM29.6 8.80001C30.4832 8.80001 31.2 9.51681 31.2 10.4C31.2 11.2832 30.4832 12 29.6 12C28.7168 12 28 11.2832 28 10.4C28 9.51681 28.7168 8.80001 29.6 8.80001ZM20 12C24.4176 12 28 15.5824 28 20C28 24.4176 24.4176 28 20 28C15.5824 28 12 24.4176 12 20C12 15.5824 15.5824 12 20 12ZM20 15.2C18.7269 15.2 17.506 15.7057 16.6059 16.6059C15.7057 17.5061 15.2 18.727 15.2 20C15.2 21.273 15.7057 22.4939 16.6059 23.3941C17.506 24.2943 18.7269 24.8 20 24.8C21.273 24.8 22.4939 24.2943 23.3941 23.3941C24.2943 22.4939 24.8 21.273 24.8 20C24.8 18.727 24.2943 17.5061 23.3941 16.6059C22.4939 15.7057 21.273 15.2 20 15.2Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_1689_215)"/>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_1689_215" x1="6.09064" y1="23.727" x2="33.9093" y2="16.273" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#45B8FB"/>
                <stop offset="0.53" stop-color="#4B85F0"/>
                <stop offset="0.9" stop-color="#5151E5"/>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

With 2 different svgs for the instagram logo, one with a `linearGradient` and one without.

And I am rendering them here:

```js
const sizeVariants = {
  // 32px
  '2xl': 'w-8 h-8',
  // 24px
  xl: 'w-6 h-6',
  // 20px
  lg: 'w-5 h-5',
  // 16px
  md: 'w-4 h-4',
  // 14px
  sm: 'w-3.5 h-3.5',
  // 12px
  xs: 'w-3 h-3',
} as const;

type Props = {
  title?: string;
  name: string;
  size?: keyof typeof sizeVariants;
  category: SpritesCategories;
  className?: string;
  rotateWhenRtl?: boolean;
  onClick?: () => void;
};

export const SpriteIcon = ({
  title,
  name,
  size,
  className = '',
  rotateWhenRtl = false,
  category,
  onClick,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  const spritePath = `/assets/icons/${category}-sprite.svg`;

  const svgStyle =
    !size && !className
      ? sizeVariants['md']
      : `${className} ${size ? sizeVariants[size] : ''} ${
          rotateWhenRtl ? 'rtl:-scale-x-100' : ''
        }`;

  return (
    <svg className={svgStyle} onClick={onClick} {...props}>
      {title ? <title>{title}</title> : null}
      <use href={`${spritePath}#${name}`}></use>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

The 'normal' one renders normally when I call the `<SpriteIcon />` component like this:

```js
 <SpriteIcon
    category={SpritesCategories.SOCIAL}
    name={socialMedia.name}
    size="2xl"
    title={socialMedia.title}
    className="mr-2"
 />
```

The svg file is named `social-sprite.svg`, the name and title that are beign passed there are `instagram` and `instagram-gradient` respectively

However the one with the `linearGradient` does not render. I'm using NextJS (v.13.4.6) with Tailwind, anyone can help?

My end goal was to apply the gradient when hovering the svg, i've tried with css but with no luck therefore I thought I could just add an svg with a gradient but it seems it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<defs>` outside of the `<symbol>`. In the following example I use this SVG document where I just replaced the complex path with a more simple one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"
 width="0" height="0" visibility="hidden"
 style="visibility: hidden;position: absolute;pointer-events:none;"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_1689_215" x1="6.09064" y1="23.727" x2="33.9093" y2="16.273" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#45B8FB"/>
      <stop offset="0.53" stop-color="#4B85F0"/>
      <stop offset="0.9" stop-color="#5151E5"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <symbol id="instagram" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none">
    <path d="M24 6A15 15 0 1025 6Z" fill="currentColor"/> 
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="instagram-gradient" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none">
    <path d="M24 6A15 15 0 1025 6Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_1689_215)"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

And there as a data URI in `<use>`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="100" height="100">
  <use href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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#instagram-gradient"/>
</svg>
```